# TYPO3 8.7 TCA Select on own Table

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x, dbal, typo3-extensions

We have a problem with a select which is defined in TCA after a core update from TYPO3 6.2 LTS to 8.7 LTS.

The problem is, that the select uses all available memory. I think, that the problem is caused by the fact, that the select in TCA selects the own table and we have a loop now.

In TYPO3 6.2 the select has worked as expected.

Can someone confirm this behavior or has a solution for this?

Best Regards

Markus Gehrig

File Configuration/TCA/Override/tt_address.php:

```
'tx_twwcprojectmanager_company' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:twwc_projectmanager/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_twwcprojectmanager_domain_model_company.tx_twwcprojectmanager_company',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'items' => array(
            array('LLL:EXT:twwc_projectmanager/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_address.tx_twwczusatzprojekte_nochoice', 0),
        ),
        'foreign_table' => 'tt_address',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY company',
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to exclude the element's uid in your foreign_table_where string:

```
'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tt_address.uid != ###THIS_UID### ORDER BY tt_address.company'
```

There are several other markers you could use in a similar context:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#foreign-table-where

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That makes sense. But I get following error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 23068864 bytes) in /var/www/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/Element/SelectSingleElement.php on line 172

Comment: This sounds like a lot of adresses to me and 128MB might be too low as a memory limit. You should increase it or ask your server admin to do that for you or find another way to reduce the result set in your foreign_table_where..

Comment: Thanks, that was it.